# AngularJS : router : load view manually from within controller

Tags: animation, angularjs, controller

Is there a way of manually loading the view from within the controller, after say some animation was triggered first? The scenario I have is the previous page content sliding up, after that the view would be updated when being off-the screen and once ready - slides back down with the new view from the new controller.

I've got already the router set up, but it just instantly replaces the view whenever the new controller is called.

Any fiddle if possible please?

Answer (score 0):

Code in Controller shouldn't manipulate DOM, directives should. Here is directive to prevent preloading content of element with "src" (by browser's parser) and show content of element only after loading, and before loading show splash with spinner:

```
directive('onloadSrc', function($compile) {
 return function(scope, element, attrs) {
  element.bind('load', function() {
    var parent = $compile(element[0].parentElement)(scope);
    if (!element.attr('src') && attrs.onloadSrc) {
      element.attr("src", attrs.onloadSrc);
      // replace this dirty hardcode with your template for splash spinner                                          
      var spinner_div = $compile('<div style="z-index: 100; width: '+element.attr('width')+'px; height: '+element.attr('height')+'px; display:block; vertical-align:middle;"><img src="/img/spinner.gif" style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin: -8px 0 0 -8px;"/></div>')(scope);
      attrs.onloadSrc = "";
      parent.prepend(spinner_div);
      element.css("display", 'none');
      attrs.xloading = spinner_div;
    }
    else {
     if (attrs.xloading) {
      attrs.xloading.remove();
      attrs.xloading = false;
      element.css("display", 'block');
    }
   }
 }
);
}});
```

To use this directive, leave empty attribute `src` of element and fill attribute `onload-src`.

Comment: Thanks @OZ_, but is that for the controller view loading? I've created a service and then inject it to the controller - in controller I call the relevant method - is that also considered a bad practice?

Comment: It's definitely not bad practice to use Service in Controller - it's what for they are made. But for manipulations with DOM AngularJS has directives. Maybe I don't understand your question - please provide some example in jsfiddle then.

Comment: Here it is - although it doesn't seem to work within jsfiddle at all: http://jsfiddle.net/scabro/Hdh78/6/

Answer (score 0):

Angular has animations build in in unstable branch, which should perfectly fit your scenario.
Just check out http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/tutorial/how-to-make-animations-with-angularjs.
`ng-view` directive has build in 'enter' and 'leave' animations.
Check you this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/nFhX8/18/ which does more less what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: That's right - it has, but none of the built in ones is what I'm after. I've got a specific requirement - view slides in > link  clicked and the current view slides up > view content is replaced outside of the window and slides in. There are also scenarios for sub-navigation sliding in after the view slides out (if link contains sub-navigation) - as you can see the standard animations just wouldn't do what I need.