# Manually change view/controller from within Typescript function

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-2013

After the user logs into my web application I want to load a new view, as I want to go from a login page to a Master/detail page.

So, I have an html fragment ready, but I am not certain how to call so that the new view gets loaded.

I have a route set up this way:

```
            .when("/master", { templateUrl: "Templates/SalonMaster.html", controller: "SalonAdminInfoCtrl" })
```

And inside my controller for logging in I have this:

```
        self.$scope.submitLogin = function () {
            dataSvc.processLogin(self.$scope.username, self.$scope.password, self.$scope.salon.Id);
            dataSvc.salon = self.$scope.salon;
            self.$scope.giftCertForm.$setPristine();
        };
```

I am thinking I should use '$window.location.href', but unless I replace the login route with the 'master' route I am not certain what I should do, or if that will work.

So, after logging in, how do I then get the correct view and controller active, since I will only switch it if the response back from the server is correct.

This question is similar, but perhaps I would need to programmatically click on a hidden link, but there should be a better approach.

[AngularJS : router : load view manually from within controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968196/angularjs-router-load-view-manually-from-within-controller?rq=1)

Comment: Are you using angular ui router or angular route?

Comment: @PSL - I believe the angular router as I put them into $routeProvider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a route for `/master/loggedin` or something and then navigate here using `$location.url(url);` only if login response was successful.

Note: `$window.location` will not trigger an angular navigation but `$location.url` will, i.e. the template / controller etc will be processed.